# How do I check to see if my subview is being touched?

Tags: iphone, touch, subview

I've been attempting to expand on a tutorial by trying to make Ryu animate only when he is touched.  However, the touch is not even being registered and I believe it has something to do with it being a subview.  Here is my code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

 if([touch view] == ryuView){
  NSLog(@"Touch");
 } else {
  NSLog(@"No touch");
 }
}

-(void) ryuAnims{
 NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],
         nil];

 ryuView.animationImages = imageArray;
 ryuView.animationDuration = 1.1;
 [ryuView startAnimating];


}



-(void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
        CGRectMake(100, 125, 150, 130)];
 ryuView = image;


 ryuView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
 ryuView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft; 
 [self.view addSubview:ryuView];
        [image release];
}
```

This code compiles fine, however, when touching or clicking on ryu, nothing happens.  I've also tried

```
if([touch view] == ryuView.image)
```

but that gives me this error: "Comparison of distinct Objective-C type 'struct UIImage *' and 'struct UIView *' lacks a cast."  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Is the `UIView` set up to receive touch events at all?

```
ryuView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

**touchesBegan** is method of **UIView** class, and it should be implemented in subclass of **UIView** (or of **UIImageView** in your case). Not in some outer class where you implement animation block!

So ensure that you create subclass of **UIImageView** e.g. **RyuImageView** and implement **touchesBegan** method. Then you should inform your object with animation block that  ryuView was touched. You can use delegate method for this. See  answer  [Xcode: How to change Image on Touching at an Image (same Position)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432176/xcode-how-to-change-image-on-touching-at-an-image-same-position/2434440#2434440) as sample.

And yes, set UIImageView's  **userInteractionEnabled** to **YES** because default value of this property of UIImageView is **NO**

do it either in initWith... method of RyuImageView:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

or in your animation block class:

```
 ryuView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```