# Making an area of a UIImage/UIScrollView "clickable"

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, uiimageview

So I have two issues to solve:

1. Detect a click on an area in an UIImageView.
2. Detect a click on an area in an UIScrollView.

I'm thinking for both, since I have the x/y coordinates from the client, I'm going to programmatically instantiate an UIButton (custom/transparent) and place it over the desired area for both the UIImageView & UIScrollViews.

I will also have an event that fires when the user selects the button. I'm thinking about providing a tag and using a signature like

```
- (IBAction) btnPress:(id)sender
```

So I can query the sender

```
 [sender tag]
```

And then make decisions based on the tag. Each button will have a unique id.
My questions are:

1. Is this a good way to do it? What would be better?
2. I'm aware of how to do all these things in IB, but not programmatically. I was under the impression connections (for IBActions) are only made in IB, so how can I wire up a button to an event all in code (I'll start googling now).

TIA.

Comment: I am not sure exactly how you would do it with a scroll view (possibly with a subclass?), but for a `UIImageView`, all you have to do is set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to YES (it defaults to NO for image views)

Comment: Yup, do as Simon said. You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432176/xcode-how-to-change-image-on-touching-at-an-image-same-position/2434440#2434440 but instead changing the image, run your event code.

Comment: Ok, thanks Simon. Jano, that link looks great, Im going to go down that path I think. Thanks, I'll report back my results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a UIButton to handle the touches, you can indeed create a custom button to place over the frame.  If you take this route, to apply a method to the button, you must do the following:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:....];
myButton.tag = // your tag;
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then when you want to call the method, it will be an IBAction method as you would expect.

```
- (IBAction)btnPress:(id)sender {
```

where `[sender tag]` will indeed get your specified button to proceed as you wish.

That being said, I might be more inclined to set up a UIGestureRecognizer on the views.  Basically, you would tag your UIImageView and/or UIScrollView, then create a gesture recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *myGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[myGesture addTarget:self action@selector(frameTouched:)];
// for the case of the imageView;
[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:myGesture];
[myGesture release];
```

Then to handle the gesture,

```
- (void)frameTouched:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    int myLogicTag = [[gesture view] tag];  // this finds the tag of the view it embodies, in this case your imageView
    // continue with your code;
}
```

Of course, if you have custom scrollView or imageView classes, you can simply override the `touchesBegan` method and do what you want from there.  I think that should cover your options pretty well, so I hope this helps

Comment: It does and actually I might go this route in the end. The prior answer, I'm not sure I need all that. Though it is a really cool way to solve it.

Comment: I ended up going this route and building a small class that i can query that'll provide the x/y/l/w for the button and i just add to the subview. Working well so far. Thanks to everyone's answers.

Comment: My pleasure.  I'm glad it helped and best of luck with the rest of your application