# Xcode: How to click image on UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am trying to make UIScrollView with list of images that will switch to different one after click. The case is to simulate selecting an image.

I have tried to use UIButton instead of UIImage and it was very easy to switch image, but I was not able to scroll them when I clicked right on button. It was scrolling only when I clicked between buttons.

Than I tried to use UIImages and it was easy to scroll, but I was not able to switch image after clicking.

I dig a little and found following post: [Xcode: How to change Image on Touching at an Image (same Position)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432176/xcode-how-to-change-image-on-touching-at-an-image-same-position)

It seems to be the thing I need, but I am doing something wrong.

My code:

```
//TouchSimpleView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TouchSimpleView : UIImageView {
    id delegate;
}
@property (retain) id delegate;
@end

@interface NSObject (TouchSimpleView)
-(void)didTouchView:(UIView *) aView;
@end


//  TouchSimpleView.m
#import "TouchSimpleView.h"
@implementation TouchSimpleView
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touchesBagan");
    if(delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didTouchView:)]) {
        [delegate didTouchView:self];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
@end
```

I am using above like that:

```
//  ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TouchSimpleView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    TouchSimpleView *touchView;
    UIImageView *bankImageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) TouchSimpleView *touchView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *bankImageView;
@end


//  ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize touchView;
@synthesize bankImageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    touchView = [[TouchSimpleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    touchView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:touchView];

    bankImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:touchView.frame];
    bankImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
    [touchView addSubview: bankImageView];
}

- (void)didTouchView:(UIView *)aView {
    NSLog(@"view touched; changing image");
}

@end
```

There is no UIScrollView that I mentioned on the beginning but I would like to make this simple example working and than add touchView to the UIScrollView.

I am very beginner in iOS programming.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    touchView = [[TouchSimpleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    touchView.delegate = self;
    touchView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    touchView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
    [self.view addSubview:touchView];
}
```

Thank you @Mundi

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `UIImageView` property  `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `YES`.
The default is `NO`.

Comment: I have sat bankImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES and did not help.

Comment: bankImageView is not a subclassed image view. You only implemented `touchesBegan` in your `TouchSimpleView` class.

Comment: Thank you @Mundi for your answer, but I am new on iOS and I do not really understand what need to be fixed.
I know what inherit is but do not know how to achieve it in iOS.
Can you please provide me with some example code as an answer?

Comment: Just make bankImageView of class TouchSimpleView instead of UIImageView and it should work.